# Symfony Mailer Twig Context in Subject Line

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5, symfony-mailer

I am using Symfony 5 and the mailer component with twig templating.  The context works fine for the body of the email, but is there not a way to apply that to the email subject line also?

Right now I'm having to manually do my own string replace, which I just can't believe this isn't possible within the same message context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of the email is not a Twig template, so it won't interpolate any variables from the template context.

You'll need to do your own interpolation when creating the actual email message and setting an email subject.